# my python shows this error: Fatal error in launcher [WinError 5] because I renamed my user folder name

Tags: python, windows, pip

I renamed my user folder name. Paths are as follows:

- `<olduser>`: my old user name
- `<renameduser>`: my new user name that I renamed from the old one

When I try to use *pip* it shows this error:

`Fatal error in launcher, unable to create process using '"c:\users\<olduser>\appdata\local\programs\python\python39.exe" "c:\users\<renameduser>\appdata\local\programs\python\python39.exe\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.`

When I try to run python it shows `access denied`. Can someone suggest a solution for me?

Comment: Avoid calling `pip` directly. Try calling `python -m pip` instead. Maybe it helps in you particular use case, maybe it does not. But in general it is always better to call `python -m pip` instead of `pip`. -- Anyway, you probably should reinstall Python if possible. There are probably ways to rescue this situation without reinstalling, but I am not sure it is worth the energy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your environment variables hasn't been updated to the new folder name?

[image: Here you have to update the path]

Answer (score 0):

Change your [PATH](https://www.makeuseof.com/python-windows-path/) and PYTHON_HOME [environment variable](https://www.techjunkie.com/environment-variables-windows-10/) to reflect your new username. If the problem persists, re-install Python and pip.